# I want to increment the data one by one so that the histogram changes in Manipulate

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics, manipulate, probability-or-statistics

```
BarChart[{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}]
```

How can I pre-populate the data from this source code and move it with `Manipulate` to show how the histogram changes when I put the data one by one into a histogram?

Comment: `Manipulate[BarChart[data[[;; n]]], {{n, 1}, 1, Length@data, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: There's no reason to delete your post. The last edited version did not make any sense. You received an answer by @BobHanlon in the form of a comment and another one by me in the form of an answer. Absolutely, no reason to try and delete my answer as an edit and then deleting the main body of your question

Answer (score 2):

@BobHanlon showed how to do it with `Manipulate`. Below I show how to export a `.gif` just in case

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]
data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
barchart = 
 Animate[BarChart[data[[1 ;; n]], Frame -> True], {n, 1, Length@data, 
   1}, AnimationRate -> 3, AnimationRunning -> True, 
  AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
Export["gif.gif", barchart]
```

> [image: gif]

Comment: Animate[BarChart[data[[1 ;; n]]   ->  What does the semicolon in the data indicate?([1 ;; n])    Is there another rewrite?

Comment: @abibi You should read the documentation on [**`Part`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) for a better understanding. `data[[m;;n]]` gives you parts of `m` through `n`